# OneToMany ManyToOne DoctrineORM Error

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm newbie with PHP. I started work with symfony but i have this problem

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $carList
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car", mappedBy="name", cascade={"persist"})
 */
     private $carList;

//getters and setters
```

}

```
     *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\CarBundle\Repository\Entity\CarRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="car")
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     *
     */
    protected $id;



    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User" , inversedBy="carList")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")

 */     
    private $name;

//getters and setters

}
```

The stacktrace says:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: name
>       at n/a

and when i run php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

> [Mapping] FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The association AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User#carList refers to the owning side field AppBundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car#name which is not
>   defined as association, but as field.
>   *The association AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User#carList refers to the owning side field Appbundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car#name which does
>   not exist

I have no idea whats going on, can you help me?

Comment: You are mixing up association names with column names. When you create an association you don't need to manually add the columns for that association, doctrine will work that out for you. Ref http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up association names with column names. When you create an association you don't need to manually add the columns for that association, doctrine will work that out for you.

This code (in the Car class) says that the $name field is a normal text column in the car table, which of course is wrong
`* @ORM\Column(name="name",type="string", length=100)`

What you're describing is that one user can own many cars, and many cars can belong to one user. I'd then call the associations owner and cars, but you are of course free to call them whatever you want. Note that you do not need to define the join columns.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $cars
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\CarBundle\Entity\Car", mappedBy="owner", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $cars;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->cars = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\CarBundle\Repository\Entity\CarRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="car")
 */
class Car
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User" , inversedBy="cars")
     */     
    private $owner;

//getters and setters

}
```

Read more: [Doctrine association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: @JhonStumber np, it might take some association mappings before one really gets it. I suggest you try to create some related entities just to generate the db schema and see how it looks, and how different associations create different types of columns/tables. I'd also recommend thinking about the layout in this post. Not sure what you're making, but at least here a car can have multiple owners, both historically and currently (not unusual for parents to co-sign on more expensive cars for their kids) etc.